# Are all the IBM QX mapping bidirectional?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, architecture

The connection between physical qubits of IBM devices are all bidirectional or there are some architectures that there existing some unidirectional connection?
I found that in IBM Quantum experience, all the device connections are bidirectional, I was wondering if there are some exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

All of the backends are bidirectional from the viewpoint of Qiskit.  The Cross-Resonance (CR) gate used in implementing the CNOT has a natural preferred direction associated with it, but accounting for the direction is done automatically by the devices, thus yielding a bi-directional topology.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the architecture of QX2 and QX3, and both of them are unidirectional. Are the two architectures still used currently? If we want to design a mapping ourselves, do we need to consider of the direction?

Comment: Qx2 has been updated and is now bidirectional. Qx3 is offline but similar to Melbourne which is also bidirectional now.

Comment: I see. Thanks!!